# iOS - An NSArray of a single NSData object saved in NSUserDefault come out to be NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm saving a customized class `DeviceInfo` in to NSDefault.

I already used `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive the object into a `NSData` object.

As I want to save an array of `deviceInfo` objects into `NSUserDefault`, I put the archived objects into an `NSArray`.

However, it seems that, when there's only one `NSData` object in the array, I always get an `NSData` object while it should be an `NSArray` object when I fetch it from `NSUserDefault`.

Why is that?

Here's the code.

```
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_deviceInfo];

NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray new];
temp = [[SDGridItemCacheTool itemsArray] mutableCopy];    //[[SDGridItemCacheTool itemsArray]] is the method the fetch the array, I paste the code below.
[temp addObject:data];
[SDGridItemCacheTool saveItemsArray:[temp copy]];
```

And the code to save and fetch data from `NSUserDefault`

```
//SDGridItemCacheTool.m
+ (NSArray *)itemsArray
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kItemsArrayCacheKey];
}

+ (void)saveItemsArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[array copy] forKey:kItemsArrayCacheKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Finally the `DeviceInfo` class:

```
@interface DeviceInfo : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* imageResString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* currentStat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* colorStatPair;

@end

@implementation DeviceInfo

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kUserDefaultDeviceTitleKey];
        _imageResString = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kUserDefaultDeviceImageResStringKey];
        _currentStat = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KUserDefaultDeviceCurrentStatKey];
        _colorStatPair = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kUserDefaultDeviceColorStatPair];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:_title forKey:kUserDefaultDeviceTitleKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_imageResString forKey:kUserDefaultDeviceImageResStringKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_currentStat forKey:KUserDefaultDeviceCurrentStatKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_colorStatPair forKey:kUserDefaultDeviceColorStatPair];
}

@end
```

Comment: You are creatng two unnecessary array objects in your first two lines of code. And there's arrayByAddingObject. And another one in saveItemsArray. Plus no need to call synchronize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

Your `itemsArray` method will return `nil` until you actually save some data. So you need to handle that properly. Your `saveItemsArray:` method needlessly does a copy of the array and it needlessly calls `synchronize`.

Updated SDGridItemCacheTool.m

```
+ (NSArray *)itemsArray
{
    NSArray *result = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kItemsArrayCacheKey];
    if (!result) {
        result = [NSArray array];
    }

    return result;
}

+ (void)saveItemsArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:kItemsArrayCacheKey];
}
```

And your code that calls these two methods needs some cleanup.

```
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_deviceInfo];

NSMutableArray *temp = [[SDGridItemCacheTool itemsArray] mutableCopy];
[temp addObject:data];
[SDGridItemCacheTool saveItemsArray:temp];
```

There was no need to create an `NSMutableArray` and then replace it. And there's no need to copy the array.

You may also wish to delete and reinstall your app to start with clean user defaults. If you have changed this code a bit, you may have a non-array stored in that key from earlier code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please give me some instructions on how to clean user defaults? And I see somewhere people says that store a mutable object in user default may cause some problems so I use a copy of the array.

Comment: "You see somewhere" - what you saw was nonsense.

Comment: You clean user defaults by deleting and reinstalling the app. And yes, it is nonsense that storing a mutable object in user defaults may cause some problems.